# Two script codes interfering on the same page

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I know I've gotten these to work before but right now the two sliders are conflicting. I'd like to be able to add multiple sliders on one page. I've changed div & class names but one slider still won't slide while the other will. I think I need to adjust something within the javascript but not sure what exactly. Any tips are appreciated!

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.container {
height:500px;
width:470px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
.container {
height:300px;
width:270px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}}
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
img + img {
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}
input[type=range] {
position: relative;
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: calc(100% + 40px);
height: 100%;
margin-left: -20px;
background-color: transparent;
outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 45px;
width: 45px;
background: #ffffff40;
border: 2px solid #ffffff50;
border-radius: 50%;
background-size: contain;
cursor: ew-resize;
}
</style>
<div class="container">

<img src="https://static.showit.co/file/8i_9h_dFRUmLz53we-7fPA/118367/pexels-mathilde-langevin-13347113.jpg" alt="">

<img id="compare" src="https://static.showit.co/file/52u9yxPRTRG-TMpsIFYFUw/118367/pexels-nati-12060729.jpg" alt="">

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" oninput="slide()">
</div>

<script>    
function slide() {
let slideValue = document.getElementById("slider").value;
document.getElementById("compare").style.clipPath =
"polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)";
console.log(
"polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)"
);
}
</script>

<br>

<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
.container2 {
height:500px;
width:470px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}}

@media only screen and (max-width: 749px) {
.container2 {
height:300px;
width:270px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}}
img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
img + img {
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 0 100%);
}
input[type=range] {
position: relative;
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: calc(100% + 40px);
height: 100%;
margin-left: -20px;
background-color: transparent;
outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 45px;
width: 45px;
background: #ffffff40;
border: 2px solid #ffffff50;
border-radius: 50%;
background-size: contain;
cursor: ew-resize;
}
</style>
<div class="container2">

<img src="https://static.showit.co/file/IfWlE8sBS3-aTYVLs-7LVg/118367/pexels-photo-
8605494.jpg" alt="">

<img id="compare2" src="https://static.showit.co/file/CPGMnv5dTSWZIJg3k4AS1Q/118367/pexels-photo-
86054942.jpg" alt="">

<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider2" oninput="slide()">
</div>


<script>    
function slide() {
let slideValue = document.getElementById("slider2").value;
document.getElementById("compare2").style.clipPath =
"polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)";
console.log(
"polygon(0 0," + slideValue + "% 0," + slideValue + "% 100%, 0 100%)"
);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have two different functions named `slide`. You need different function names.

Comment: Or change the function so it takes the ID as a parameter, and call it with the appropriate parameter from each slider.